# Preserve the scroll position of a Page

Tags: sapui5

I have a page with many elements (forms and tables)
When I want add a row in a table I scroll the page to the table, I press a button to add a row, edit the info in a popup and press OK.

[image]

Then I insert the new row in the model and `refresh()` the model.
At this point the page auto scroll at the top, but I don't want this behavior! 
I want that the page stay in the same Y position!
I see that `sap.m.page` has scrollTo function https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Page.html#scrollTo
but I don't know how take the position before the `refresh()`

Comment: I know this is old, but how do you close the Popover? The scrolling only happens if you destroy the Popover. If you just close it, there should be no scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Page does unfortunately not have an API to get the current scroll position, but the idea is a good one we consider.

As a workaround you could access some private method of the Page - but only if you accept the risk that it breaks with a future version of UI5:
`page.getScrollDelegate().getScrollTop()`
To make it safer you should verify both methods exist before calling them and also check the returned value for plausibility. Then you are pretty safe that in the worst case it will again scroll to the top in some future UI5 version.

Comment: Ok, I have retrieved the current position by `getScrollTop()` and I want use this parameter in `scrollTo` function.
I try to do `page.scrollTo(10)` (for example) but I not see any scoll

Comment: Well, assuming there IS enough content to scroll, I'm pretty sure scrollTo() works.http://jsbin.com/bigeyasacu/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

you have to fill the `iTime` parameter in `scrollTo` function - e.g. `srollTo(100, 1)` - then it works
using `0` for `iTime` does not work